# C# Equivalent of CURL Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, curl, model-view-controller

I want to convert the below CURL to C#

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -XPOST https://auth.razorpay.com/token-d '{  "client_id": "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>",  "client_secret": "<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>",  "grant_type": "authorization_code",  "redirect_uri": "http://example.com/razorpay_callback",  "code": "def50200d844dc80cc44dce2c665d07a374d76802",  "mode": "test"}
```

This is what I have tried; I get an exception saying "Bad Request"

```
 HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://auth.razorpay.com/token");
        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webrequest.Headers.Add("client_id", "ClientId");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("client_secret", "Secret");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("redirect_uri", "RazorPayCallBackURL");
        webrequest.Headers.Add("code", code);
        webrequest.Headers.Add("mode", "test");
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: The `-d` option specifies the content of the POSTed data, instead of adding all those headers maybe you should set the request's content to that blob of JSON

Comment: Content-Type is the key here, _JSON_ indicates that the body will be sent as a json payload, the `-H` in the curl was only for the `Content-Type` but in C# we can set that through the `webrequest.ContentType` helper property.